# Каковы преимущества/недостатки Nemerle по сравнению с С#?

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте! Большую часть времени я пишу на С#, но мне всегда не хватало в этом прекрасном языке макросов (однажды попробовав макросы LISP, трудно остановиться хД). И вот вчера я наткнулся на статью про язык *Nemerle*. Из этой статьи я узнал, что сей язык является Net-совместимым (да и вообще изначально проектировался под Net), имеет достаточно простой синтаксис и, что главное, обладает очень мощным функционалом для создания макросов. В общем, в той статье все выглядело как-то уж слишком радужно, я даже удивился, что о таком хорошем языке никогда не слышал, да и на StackOverflow для него даже нет тэга. Так что решил спросить вашего мнения: что на деле из себя представляет Nemerle, какие плюсы и минусы по сравнению с тем же С# он имеет?

P.S. - вопрос не является субъективным. По поводу любой вещи в мире можно вполне объективно сказать ее плюсы и минусы, что я и прошу

Comment: Судя по всему Nemerle мертв.

Comment: Минус любого нестандартного языка в том, что его никто не знает. Если вы захотите на реальном проекте его использовать, вам просто не позволят этого сделать. Никому не нужен код, который никто не может поддерживать.

Comment: Главный плюс вы сами назвали: макросы. Минус: язык не поддерживается крупной компанией, сообщество мало. Вам прямая дорога на rsdn.org - именно там тусуются немерлисты.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Мда уж. Интересная ситуация складывается. Условный Питон пиарится на каждом углу, а многообещающие языки, требующие небольшой шлифовки, пылятся на задворках небольших комьюнити...

Comment: Там вроде только один немерлист, мой почти тёзка.

Comment: @Kir_Antipov: Вот JS — не самый лучший язык, а ведь взлетел.

Comment: @VladD, я сначала думал, что это вы занимались, когда читал статьи на хабре/rsdn, но смутила двойка на конце ника (VladD2) :)